# Static generic extension for Array for help function for iterated async callbacks

Tags: swift

I have two help methods that I want to move to an extension to increase it's reusability. The two methods manages multiple callbacks when calling parallell http request. However when making the methods static and moving them to an extension I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[Action]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

The code is

```
extension Array
{
    private static func iterateObjectList<Type>(objectList:[Type], multiplier:Int=1, foreach:(object:Type, (newObject:Type?, error:NSError?) -> Void) -> (), finally: (objectList:[Type], errorList:[NSError]) -> Void)
    {
        var iterationsLeft = objectList.count * multiplier
        var errorList:[NSError] = []
        var returnObjectList:[Type] = []
        if (iterationsLeft == 0) {
            finally (objectList:objectList, errorList:[])
        }
        for object:Type in objectList {
            foreach (object:object, { (requestObject, requestError) -> Void in

                iterationsLeft -= 1
                if (requestError != nil) {
                    errorList.append(requestError!);
                }
                if (requestObject != nil) {
                    returnObjectList.append(requestObject!)
                }
                if (iterationsLeft <= 0) {
                    finally (objectList:returnObjectList, errorList:errorList)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private static func simpleIterate<Type>(objectList:[Type], multiplier:Int=1, foreach:(object:Type, Void -> Void) -> (), finally: Void -> Void)
    {
        var iterationsLeft = objectList.count * multiplier

        if (iterationsLeft == 0) {
            finally ()
        }
        for object:Type in objectList {
            foreach (object:object, { Void -> Void in

                iterationsLeft -= 1
                if (iterationsLeft <= 0) {
                    finally ()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The error is when using the methods:

```
Array.iterateObjectList(actions, foreach: { (action, iterationComplete) -> () in
    self.fetchStatusAndUpdateAction(action, callback: { (error) -> Void in
        iterationComplete(newObject: action, error:error)
    })
}, finally: { (objectList, errorList) -> Void in
    callback(error: errorList.first)
})
```

where actions is of type [Action] where Action is a custom object.

Comment: `Type` is a reserved keyword. Maybe that could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: No, not the case. Have worked before when not in an extension. Also tried to change to ´T´ but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
public struct Array<Element>
```

is a generic type, and in

```
Array.iterateObjectList(actions, foreach: { (action, iterationComplete) -> () in
    // ...
}, finally: { (objectList, errorList) -> Void in
    // ...
})
```

the compiler cannot infer what `Element` should be. You *could*
make it compile as

```
Array<Action>.iterateObjectList(actions, foreach: { (action, iterationComplete) -> () in
    // ...
    }, finally: { (objectList, errorList) -> Void in
    // ...
})
```

or even

```
Array<Int>.iterateObjectList(...)
```

The array `Element` is unrelated to your generic placeholder `Type`,
so any type will do.

But the *better solution* would be to make the static method an
instance method:

```
func iterateObjectList(multiplier:Int=1, foreach:(object:Element, (newObject:Element?, error:NSError?) -> Void) -> (), finally: (objectList:[Element], errorList:[NSError]) -> Void)
{
    // Your code with `Type` replaced by `Element`,
    // and `objectList` replaced by `self`.
    // ...
}
```

and call it on the `actions` array:

```
actions.iterateObjectList(foreach: { (action, iterationComplete) -> () in
    // ...
    }, finally: { (objectList, errorList) -> Void in
    // ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks. `Array<Action>` worked just fine. I also tried to make the it an instance method. However I then got the error `Cannot convert value of type Array<Element> to expected argument type [_]` on the rows where I use `self` instead of `objectList` in `iterateObjectList` method. Any thoughts there?

Comment: That error if on the row of `finally (objectList:self, errorList:[])`. On the row `for object:Type in self {` I get the error `Element is not convertible to Type`.

Comment: @Sunkas: As I indicated in the code comments, `Type` has to be replaced by `Element`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works fine as instance method! Sweet!